# Why does my picture not have arrows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, arrows

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
%Evita problemas con tildes y caracteres especiales
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%figuras fantásticas
\usepackage{tikz}
%Secciones con formato
\usepackage{sectsty}
%Formato del Documento
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
%Inclusión de colores en el documento.
\usepackage{xcolor}
%Inclusión de imágenes estricta
\usepackage{float}
%Formato de entornos de enunciados matemáticos
\usepackage{amsthm}
%Más simbolos utiles
\usepackage{mathtools}
%Cosas en Español
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%Letras de conjuntos notables
\usepackage{dsfont}
%Más simbolos matemáticos útiles
\usepackage{amssymb}
%Inclusión de imágenes
\usepackage{graphicx}
%Comentarios Largos
\usepackage{comment}
%Citas y Referencias
\usepackage{apacite}
%Editando las etiquetas de las numeraciones
\usepackage{enumitem}
%Caritas
\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            %Los elementos
            \node at (0,3) {$A$};
            \node at (0,0) {$A/(A \cap N)$};
            \node at (3,3) {$(A + N)/N$};
            %Las lineas
            \draw [->] (0.3,3) -- (1.8,3);
            \draw [->] (0,2.7) -- (0,0.3);
            \draw [->] (0.3,0.3) -- (2.7,2.7);
            %Las Etiquetas:
            \node [above] at (1.2,3) {$\psi$};
            \node [below] at (1.2,3) {\tiny{Sobre.}};
            \node [left] at (0,1.5) {$\Pi$};
            \node [below right] at (1.5,1.5) {$\cong$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Lo que tenemos hasta ahora}
        \label{F3.1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Lo que me sale]

As you may see I hacve the graph but the arrowheads are not there.

My questions..

1. What is wrong with its code?
2. How can I costumize the arrow I would like to add `$\twoheadrightarrow$` or `$\hookrightarrow$`

Here is the error I have:

> Timed out. Sorry, your compile took too long to run and timed out.
> This may be due to a LaTeX error, or a large number of high-res images
> or complicated diagrams.
>
> Learn how to fix compile timeouts.

Comment: Please have a look at the `tikz-cd` package. To answer the question why the arrow heads get dropped, please provide a complete code. Maybe you have a `\tikzset{>=...}` somewhere?

Comment: 1. Code works fine for me (there are arrows there in the pdf produced by your code). Try zoom in on your pdf viewer... Possibly your viewer fails with your current zoom.

Comment: @koleygr I added the error I have on my question...

Comment: @user238301 I do not have this code you mention. I only have imported a tikz pacakge with \usepackage{tikz}. I do not thing it is a good idea to send all the code it is a long homework.

Comment: Please add the code needed (including font settings) in your example ...

Comment: Are you using `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` in your preamble?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. It's very hard to help you when you just post a fragment of code. This doesn't mean you should show us all your code, but that you need to give us a minimal document that shows the problem.The fact that you have errors tells you that something else is going on here. Generally only the first error TeX encounters is relevant, since the others cascade from there, and as @JuanCastaño suggests this is likely to with an interaction with `babel`.

Comment: Yes, but in order to test whether what I think is the reason for the arrows not showing up you could just replace `\begin{tikzpicture}` by `\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]`, say.

Comment: I do not know what happened but when I write in a new File I does not have errors!

Comment: @JuanCastaño Nop :(

Comment: @user238301 It is not the problem :(

Comment: I added all the pacakges and I presents errors :(

Comment: @AlanMunn Is it enough the new code?

Comment: Add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` after `\usepackage{tikz}` and remove the line that has only a `\draw` (i.e. without a semicolon), then your code works, and there will be arrows.

Comment: @GermánLópez Yes, this is better, although many of the packages you're loading aren't relevant to the problem. But the comment by about `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`  and removing the unfinished `\draw` command solves your immediate problem.

Comment: And now you know why we **always** ask for full (but minimal) examples. We could easily have fixed this 45min ago.

Comment: @user238301 You should make this an answer (and perhaps explain why the loading the TikZ `babel` library is necessary.) When you add that the error becomes much more helpful, too!

Comment: @user238301 Thank you! It was the trick

Comment: @daleif Yep I see :)

Comment: @AlanMunn I do not know Why do I delete the command. I will add it!

Comment: @AlanMunn Please feel free to write an answer. I think that the current answer is a very good fit, and I also think that the problems by the OP have been solved in the comments. In many ways this seems to be an XY problem, i.e. the question is not really why the arrows disappear but to which extent one should expect a consistent output if one ignores error messages.

Comment: @AlanMunn I appreciate your answer if possible I solved the problem but I do not which is the cause!

Comment: Guys! there is a solution to my question 2?

Comment: Your error message is completely different than the error you started with.  Without a minimal working example, we won't be able to help you with a timeout error.  Changing the question after getting an answer is bad form.  And question 2 is also answered by the existing answer.

Comment: See solution below for hooked arrow and doubled arrowhead.

Comment: @Teepeemm Sorry, I changed since people asked for it!

Comment: @SandyG I was trying to find a solution only with TiKz

Comment: You can do this using only TikZ as explained in the beginning of my solution.

Comment: Ok, got it! @SandyG

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do this from scratch (without `tikz-cd`) you can make a double arrowhead by using `\draw [->>]`. The hooked arrow can be obtained using `\draw [right hook->]`, but first you must load the `arrows` library:

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
```

As was mentioned in the comments, you should also add the `babel` library:

```
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
```

Do these right after `\usepackage{tikz}`.

But this type of diagram is basically what `tikz-cd` was designed for.

[image]

The code is much simpler than designing the diagram from scratch:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2cm]
A\arrow[r,"\psi","\mathrm{Sobre.}"']\arrow[d,"\Pi"'] & (A+N)/N\\
A/(A\cap N)\arrow[ur,"\cong"']
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

To add a hook, add `hookrightarrow` to the code. For example:

```
\arrow[r,hookrightarrow,"\psi","\mathrm{Sobre.}"']
```

To get a double arrowhead, use `->>`. For example:

```
A/(A\cap N)\arrow[ur,->>,"\cong"']
```

Comment: Is it impossible to do the diagram from scratch? I am learning with this package in my class and my teacher encourage us to use it!

Comment: @daleif, yes that's a typo. Fixed now. Thanks. Good call on `babel` also.

Comment: @GermánLópez sure, but you need to show us the full code such that we can compile your sniplet on our systems. Otherwise we cannot help you. In this case `tikz-cd` is just much much faster to use

Comment: @daleif Thank you! However, I suppose my teacher will prefer the answer of the comments since he knows a lot of the package tickz. Althought, I appreciate your time and answer you are the best!

Comment: @GermánLópez probably more likely your teacher has never heard of tikz-cd, why do so much by hand...

Comment: @daleif Maybe XD

Comment: @GermánLópez There is no point in doing the diagram by hand as your teacher seem to love to. The output of `tikz-cd` is definitely superior in quality and the code is ***much*** easier.

Comment: I suppose he loves it since we are still learning how to work on it. I will ask him.

Answer (score 1):

I add my proposal using `xy` package: just a continue comment of `@daleif`....probably more likely your teacher know of `xy` package :-)))).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
     \xymatrix@R=4pc@C=2pc{
     A \ar[r]^(.35){\psi}_(.35){\mathrm{Sobre.}} \ar[d]_{\Pi}& (A+N)/N \\
     A/(A\cap N) \ar[ur]_{\cong}& 
     }
\end{document}
```

[image]

The lines are all straight. It is just a problem with the display of the `pdf` generated by Papeeria, an online tool for compiling in `LaTeX`.
See this zoom-in:

[image]

**Addendum:** *I have restrict the code of the OP and the arrows appear*: I think that the problem is `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` (see in fact the explanation of the user @Sandy G). In fact if I put it I will have:

```
Argument of \language@active@arg> has an extra }. [            \draw [->]]
/main.tex :16   Paragraph ended before \language@active@arg> was complete. [            \draw [->]]
/main.tex :16   Paragraph ended before \pgfkeys@addpath was complete. [            \draw [->]]
/main.tex :16   Missing \endcsname inserted. [            \draw [->]]
/main.tex :16   Missing \endcsname inserted. [            \draw [->]]
/main.tex :16   Missing \endcsname inserted. [            \draw [->]]
/main.tex :16   Paragraph ended before \pgfkeys@splitter was complete. [            \draw [->]]
```

Here there is a compilable MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            %Los elementos
            \node at (0,3) {$A$};
            \node at (0,0) {$A/(A \cap N)$};
            \node at (3,3) {$(A + N)/N$};
            %Las lineas
            \draw [->] (0.3,3) -- (1.8,3);
            \draw [->] (0,2.7) -- (0,0.3);
            \draw [->] (0.3,0.3) -- (2.7,2.7);
            %Las Etiquetas:
            \node [above] at (1.2,3) {$\psi$};
            \node [below] at (1.2,3) {\tiny{Sobre.}};
            \node [left] at (0,1.5) {$\Pi$};
            \node [below right] at (1.5,1.5) {$\cong$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Lo que tenemos hasta ahora}
        \label{F3.1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Got it!